# Is FLIP-140 still correct in how it describes sorting/spilling data?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[FLIP-140](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-140%3A+Introduce+batch-style+execution+for+bounded+keyed+streams) states:

> We will introduce a sorting step (with potential spilling, reusing the UnilateralSortMerger implementation) before every keyed operator for sorting/grouping inputs by their keys. This will allow us to process records in per-key groups, which will enable us to use a simplified implementation of a StateBackend that is not organized in key groups and only ever keeps values for a single key.
>
> The single key at a time execution will be used for the Batch style execution as decided by the algorithm described in FLIP-134: DataStream Semantics for Bounded Input .
>
> Moreover it will be possible to disable it through a execution.sorted-shuffles.enabled configuration option.

However I see not documentation for `execution.sorted-shuffles.enabled`, and no references to it in the code. So is the above description of how things work still correct? Wondering how the "only keep one key's state around" would work without sorting.

Answer (score 1):

[This code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/56e91700ca56f5535f677314167b94b476eb6c3f/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/graph/StreamGraphGenerator.java#L429) makes me think that both the sorting and special state backend are being used with batch execution:

```java
private void setBatchStateBackendAndTimerService(StreamGraph graph) {
    boolean useStateBackend = configuration.get(ExecutionOptions.USE_BATCH_STATE_BACKEND);
    boolean sortInputs = configuration.get(ExecutionOptions.SORT_INPUTS);
    checkState(
            !useStateBackend || sortInputs,
            "Batch state backend requires the sorted inputs to be enabled!");

    if (useStateBackend) {
        LOG.debug("Using BATCH execution state backend and timer service.");
        graph.setStateBackend(new BatchExecutionStateBackend());
        graph.setChangelogStateBackendEnabled(TernaryBoolean.FALSE);
        graph.setCheckpointStorage(new BatchExecutionCheckpointStorage());
        graph.setTimerServiceProvider(
                BatchExecutionInternalTimeServiceManager::create);
    } else {
        graph.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
        graph.setChangelogStateBackendEnabled(changelogStateBackendEnabled);
    }
}
```